# Atom single click to open file

Tags: click, settings, text-editor, atom-editor

In the Atom text editor, I previously had a setting where my files would open with a single click, I now have to double click to open them.

How can I change it back to a single click?

I feel that it should be within a setting somewhere in the Atom core packages, but so far I have had no luck finding the setting

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a feature called "pending panes" since version 1.6. More information on Atom's blog: http://blog.atom.io/2016/03/17/atom-1-6-and-1-7-beta.html

You can deactivate it in the core settings (look for "allow pending panes").

Answer (score 2):

Even after disabling "pending panes" it will strangely still require you to double-click a file to open it. To get back to the simpler functionality of single-click to open and no silly pending panes, install the [single-click-open](https://atom.io/packages/single-click-open) package.